# Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm currently working on a school project. The assignment is to write the implementation of a templated binary search tree given the corresponding header file.

My issue is that since it's templated, I'm not sure how to do comparisons between data items when inserting or finding.

Here is the header file:

```
template < typename DataType, class KeyType >    // DataType : tree data item
class BSTree                                     // KeyType : key field
{
  public:

// Constructor
BSTree ();                         // Default constructor
BSTree ( const BSTree<DataType,KeyType>& other );   // Copy constructor
BSTree& operator= ( const BSTree<DataType,KeyType>& other );
                      // Overloaded assignment operator

// Destructor
~BSTree ();

// Binary search tree manipulation operations
void insert ( const DataType& newDataItem );  // Insert data item
bool retrieve ( const KeyType& searchKey, DataType& searchDataItem ) const;
                                              // Retrieve data item
bool remove ( const KeyType& deleteKey );            // Remove data item
void writeKeys () const;                      // Output keys
void clear ();                                // Clear tree

// Binary search tree status operations
bool isEmpty () const;                        // Tree is empty
// !! isFull() has been retired. Not very useful in a linked structure.

// Output the tree structure -- used in testing/debugging
void showStructure () const;

// In-lab operations
int getHeight () const;                       // Height of tree
int getCount () const;            // Number of nodes in tree
void writeLessThan ( const KeyType& searchKey ) const; // Output keys < searchKey

protected:

class BSTreeNode                  // Inner class: facilitator for the BSTree class
{
  public:

    // Constructor
    BSTreeNode ( const DataType &nodeDataItem, BSTreeNode *leftPtr, BSTreeNode *rightPtr );

    // Data members
    DataType dataItem;         // Binary search tree data item
    BSTreeNode *left,    // Pointer to the left child
               *right;   // Pointer to the right child
};

// Recursive helpers for the public member functions -- insert
// prototypes of these functions here.
void showHelper      ( BSTreeNode *p, int level ) const;


// Data member
BSTreeNode *root;   // Pointer to the root node
};
```

The function in question is insert().

I have the following code:

```
template <typename DataType, class KeyType>
void BSTree< DataType,  KeyType>::insert(const DataType& newDataItem)
{
if(isEmpty())
    {
        root = new BSTreeNode(newDataItem, NULL, NULL);
    }

else
    {
        BSTreeNode *ptr = root;
        while(ptr != NULL)
            {
                if((*ptr)>dataItem > newDataItem)
                    {
                        ptr = ptr->left;
                    }

                else if((*ptr).dataItem < newDataItem)
                    {
                        ptr = ptr->right;
                    }
            }
        ptr = new BSTreeNode(newDataItem, NULL, NULL);
    }
}
```

And I receive the following error:

```
44 E:\School\302\Labs\7\BSTree.cpp no match for 'operator>' in 'ptr->BSTree<TestData, int>::BSTreeNode::dataItem > newDataItem' 

49 E:\School\302\Labs\7\BSTree.cpp no match for 'operator<' in 'ptr->BSTree<TestData, int>::BSTreeNode::dataItem < newDataItem'
```

How do I deal with this? Do I need to write an overloaded operator, and if so, how do I begin?

This is where insert is called:

```
class TestData
{
  public:

void setKey ( int newKey )
    { keyField = newKey; }   // Set the key

int getKey () const
    { return keyField; }     // Returns the key

  private:

int keyField;                // Key for the data item
};

int main()
{
BSTree<TestData,int> testTree;   // Test binary search tree
TestData testData;               // Binary search tree data item
int inputKey;                    // User input key
char cmd;                        // Input command

print_help();

do
{
    testTree.showStructure();                     // Output tree

    cout << endl << "Command: ";                  // Read command
    cin >> cmd;
    if ( cmd == '+'  ||  cmd == '?'  ||
         cmd == '-'  ||  cmd == '<'     )
       cin >> inputKey;

    switch ( cmd )
    {
      case 'P' : case 'p' :
           print_help();
           break; 

      case '+' :                                  // insert
           testData.setKey(inputKey);
           cout << "Insert : key = " << testData.getKey()
                << endl;
           testTree.insert(testData);
           break;

}
```

I didn't include the rest of the switch because it wasn't needed for the example.

I'm assuming that the issue is because I'm comparing two different datatypes or attempting too. How do I get around this?

I solved my problem with the following code:

```
template <typename DataType, class KeyType>
void BSTree< DataType,  KeyType>::insert(const DataType& newDataItem)
{
BSTreeNode* temp = new BSTreeNode(newDataItem, NULL, NULL);
if(isEmpty())
    {
        root = temp;
    }

else
    {
        BSTreeNode* ptr = root;
        while(ptr != NULL)
            {
                if(ptr > temp)
                    {
                        ptr = ptr->left;
                    }

                else
                    {
                        ptr = ptr->right;
                    }
            }
        ptr = temp;
    }
}
```

and

```
template <typename DataType, class KeyType>
bool BSTree<DataType, KeyType>::BSTreeNode::operator>(const BSTreeNode*& other)
{
if((*other).dataItem < (*this).dataItem)
    {
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Does `TestData` have comparison operators?

Comment: When you say TestData, what are you referring to?

Comment: The type you passed in as the first template argument.

Comment: DataType for this project is mostly going to be an int value, but there are no functions written in the class for operators.

Comment: I stubbed out the constructors, and added a main() such as this: `int main() { BSTree<int, int> bt; bt.insert(10); }` and found no issues compiling or linking (this is after the change is made that was mentioned in the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you meant to add a -> after *ptr and not > after

```
if((*ptr)>dataItem > newDataItem)
```

though it will still be incorrect. A couple of suggestions:

1. You are not handling the condition when data items are equal. An easy fix is to just replace else-if with else.
2. (*ptr).dataItem should be replaced with ptr->dataItem

Still, from the error it looks like you need to overload < and > operators for your data type. Could you please update your post with the actual calling code?

Comment: I edited my original post to have the code where the insert function is called

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. For reference, STL containers require the implementation of '<' less than operator and nothing more - so pretty much what you ended up doing with '>'.

Answer (score 0):

For example, look at the [Compare template parameter passed to std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Your template should call its Compare function.

Its default Compare method should be std::less.

A type supports std::less if it defines `operator <`; if it doesn't want to do that then it can pass a non-default compare function as a template parameter to your template.

You don't need to define `operator >` as well because you can write your template code to test `if (b < a)` instead of `if (a < b)`.

Comment: I guess my question is, how do I do that? Am I going to overload the operator <?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the following overloads (note, this is what you need to do, this is not finished yet) :

```
class BSTreeNode                  // Inner class: facilitator for the BSTree class
{
  public:

    // Constructor
    BSTreeNode ( const DataType &nodeDataItem, BSTreeNode *leftPtr, BSTreeNode *rightPtr );
    // New overloads
    inline bool operator< (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }
    inline bool operator> (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){return  operator< (rhs,lhs);}

    // Data members
    DataType dataItem;         // Binary search tree data item
    BSTreeNode *left,    // Pointer to the left child
               *right;   // Pointer to the right child
};
```

**You are not finished yet**

You need to add functionality to your BSTree to extend this Node overloads

```
// Binary search tree manipulation operations
void insert ( const DataType& newDataItem );  // Insert data item
bool retrieve ( const KeyType& searchKey, DataType& searchDataItem ) const;
inline bool operator< (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ return this->dataItem->operator<(lhs,rhs); }
inline bool operator> (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ return this->dataItem->operator>(lhs,rhs); }
```

**Our you could define them globally as part of your namespace**

```
namespace MyBSTree 
{
  inline bool operator< (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ return this->dataItem->operator<(lhs,rhs); }
  inline bool operator> (const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ return this->dataItem->operator>(lhs,rhs); }
}
```

#### OR

You could extract the last value instead of using the Node Object in your comparison. Go deep a create a get for the inner value, this way the comparison would be with the basic datatype and not with the Object.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same book. I found that because we are given the "container" type of the object through the DataType parameter, I could instantiate a holding DataType item and call the .getKey() function. It worked well. This is probably way past the due date on this, but this idea helped a lot with the other structures in the book. Here's an idea of what I mean.

```
template<typename DataType, typename KeyType>
void BSTree<DataType,KeyType>::insert ( const DataType& newDataItem )
   {
    DataType hold = newDataItem;
    KeyType holdKey = newDataItem.getKey(); //All our parameters must have getKey() return int
    insertHelper( root, holdKey, newDataItem ); // or however yours went
   }
```

This allows you to just compare the key values by creating dummy holders and calling the dummy's .getKey().

EDIT: Sorry, put the wrong recipient data type as getKey return, but you should get the idea. Strings have a built in comparison operator, so you don't have to rewrite it for each class/struct.